# Access relation of pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have three models `Bill`, `Product` and `Process`. `Bill` has a ManyToMany relationship with `Product` and the pivot table have some extra fields. I write the `Bill` model class like follow:

```
<?php
    class Bill extends Model
    {
           function products(){
                return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class)
                    ->withPivot('process_id') // the id of the Process 
                    ->withTimestamps();
            }
    }
```

The `Process` model is a simple table with an `id` and a `name`. I am associating the id in the pivot table for reference the Process, the name could change over time but still referring the same concept so I can't associate the name.

The show page for a single `Bill` lists the products associated in a table like follow:

```
@foreach($bill->products as $product)
     <tr>
        <td>{{$product->barcode}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->pivot->process_id}}</td> 
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

So the problem is that I need the name of the process, but I have the id. I'm not sure how I could get the name.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use an own Pivot Model, e.g. `ProductBill` in order to achieve this.

```
class ProductBill extends Pivot {

    public function process() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Process::class);
    }

}
```

By *using* this model in your `products` relation on `Bill`

```
class Bill extends Model {

    function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class)
            ->withPivot('process_id')
            ->using(ProductBill::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

When accessing `$product->pivot` you should get an instance of `ProductBill` now, hence you should be able to do the following:

```
<td>{{$product->pivot->process->name}}</td>
```

(Unfortunatelly I not able to doublecheck right now :/)

Answer (score 1):

Without having a direct relation to `Process` you will likely need to add a helper on your `Product` model to get the name of `Process`.

In your Product model:

```
public function processName($processId) {
    return Process::where('id', $processId)->pluck('name')->first();
}
```

In your view:

```
<td>{{$product->processName($product->pivot->process_id) }}</td>
```

There may be a better way, but concept this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the most elegant of solutions. but you could always simply do:

```
Process::find($product->pivot->process_id)->name;
```

I wouldn't advice this though as you are looping through an array already, so the overheads to doing something like this would be quite large.

Another solution would be to create a Pivot class called say `BillProductPivot` which would have a relationship to return both `Product` and `Process`, then when you call them you should be using eager loading to get the relationships. end product might look like this:

```
$bill->load('productPivots', 'productPivot.process', 'productPivot.product');

@foreach($bill->productPivots as $productPivot)
 <tr>
    <td>{{$productPivot->product->barcode}}</td>
    <td>{{$productPivot->process->name}}</td> 
 </tr>
@endforeach
```